# IPython notebook in production

Tags: django, ipython, upstart, jupyter-notebook, django-shell

I'm trying to run IPython on a production ubuntu server. I want to control it with upstart.

I have a bash script that properly invokes it in the foreground but it doesn't work when invoked through upstart. I'm not sure how to debug the problem other than piping the upstart script's output to a file, which just confirms that the IPython console dashboard properly shows up.

I'm using django-extensions with the following configuration:

```
IPYTHON_ARGUMENTS = [
    '--ext', 'django_extensions.management.notebook_extension',
    '--pylab=inline',
    '--profile=myprofile',
]
```

My bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

cd /home/ubuntu/myproject

exec venv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/myproject/manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No idea what can be the reason.

Did you had a look at [Hydra](https://github.com/cni/ipython-hydra) that have been designed to launch multiple IPython server?